# PasteSpecial (Values) in "copy if code"

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a copy-if routine where I have had trouble finding how to paste values only. Can someone please help?

My routine is as follows:

```
Sub CopyRowsAcross()

Dim i As Integer

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Workbooks("Bok2.xlsx").Sheets("Ark1")

Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Workbooks("Bok2.xlsx").Sheets("Ark2")

Dim ws3 As Worksheet: Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ark1")



For i = 2 To ws1.Range("A100").End(xlUp).Row

If ws1.Cells(i, 1) = "Videreføres" Then ws2.Range("B1:B100")(i).Copy ws3.Range("A1:A100")(ws3.Cells(ws3.Range("A1:A100").Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1)

If ws1.Cells(i, 1) = "Videreføres" Then ws2.Range("C1:C100")(i).Copy ws3.Range("B1:B100")(ws3.Cells(ws3.Range("B1:B100").Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 0)

If ws1.Cells(i, 1) = "Videreføres" Then ws2.Range("E1:E100")(i).Copy ws3.Range("C1:C100")(ws3.Cells(ws3.Range("C1:C100").Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 0)

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just pasting what you've copied where as in fact you need to use the `PasteSpecial` function. Try looking at this:

```
Sub CopyRowsAcross()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Workbooks("Bok2.xlsx").Sheets("Ark1")
    Set ws2 = Workbooks("Bok2.xlsx").Sheets("Ark2")
    Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ark1")

    For i = 2 To ws1.Range("A100").End(xlUp).Row
        If ws1.Cells(i, 1) = "Videreføres" Then
            With ws2
                .Range("B1:B100")(i).Copy
                ws3.Range("A1:A100")(ws3.Cells(ws3.Range("A1:A100").Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                .Range("C1:C100")(i).Copy
                ws3.Range("B1:B100")(ws3.Cells(ws3.Range("B1:B100").Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                .Range("E1:E100")(i).Copy
                ws3.Range("C1:C100")(ws3.Cells(ws3.Range("C1:C100").Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you very much!